# How to write unit test for RxJava CompositeSubscription

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java

```
@Override public void onBarcodeReceived(final String barcode) {
    view.showProgress();
    if (!textUtil.isEmpty(barcode)) {
      subscriptions.add(
          interactor.getSearchResultByBarcode(barcode).subscribe(subscriberForSearchResults(true)));
    }
  }

  private Subscriber<PriceAndStockActivityViewModel> subscriberForSearchResults(
      boolean fromBarcode) {
    return new BaseSubscriber<PriceAndStockActivityViewModel>() {
      @Override public void onNext(PriceAndStockActivityViewModel priceAndStockActivityViewModel) {
        super.onNext(priceAndStockActivityViewModel);
        view.updateView(priceAndStockActivityViewModel);
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
        super.onError(e);
        view.hideProgress();
        view.organizeScreenComponentsByVisibility(true);
        view.onError(e);
      }
    };
  }
```

I've wanted to test method called onBarcodeReceived like below

```
@Test public void should_updateViewByViewModel_when_AnyBarcodeReceived() {
    String barcode = "123123123";
    PriceAndStockActivityViewModel viewModel = getPriceAndStockActivityViewModel(barcode);
    when(textUtil.isEmpty(barcode)).thenReturn(false);
    when(interactor.getSearchResultByBarcode(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.just(viewModel));

    presenter.onBarcodeReceived(barcode);

    verify(view).showProgress();
    verify(interactor).getSearchResultByBarcode(anyString());
    verify(view).updateView(any(PriceAndStockActivityViewModel.class));
  }
```

Since onNext runs in a different thread its normal not to reach view.updateView. It looks simple but I couldn't find how to solve it. Is there any way to verify updateView?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because actually my implementation was correct but there was different error because of me. no any relation with the code. people can confuse having red the question. please delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume `getSearchResultByBarcode()` works on a background thread. So I wonder how you're able to change your UI from this background thread?

I'd change the execution of your `subscriber` to Android's main thread, so that you can safely manipulate the view, regardless if the thread of `getSearchResultByBarcode()` changes in the future. However will not hardcode the `Scheduler` directly, rather lets inject it in the presenter class, for example via the constructor. Of course when you're creating the "real" presenter, you'd pass in `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`:

```
public MyPresenter(, Scheduler observeScheduler) {
    ...
    this.observeScheduler = observeScheduler;
}

....

@Override 
public void onBarcodeReceived(final String barcode) {
     view.showProgress();
     if (!textUtil.isEmpty(barcode)) {
          subscriptions.add(interactor.getSearchResultByBarcode(barcode)
                .observeOn(observeScheduler)
                .subscribe(subscriberForSearchResults(true)));
     }
}
```

Then in your test, when constructing the `Presenter` you'd use `Schedulers.immediate()` (if you're using RxJava 1.x or `Schedulers.trampoline()` if you're using RxJava 2.x version. That should work without using any `timeout()`s in your Unit tests with Mockito ... after all you want them to run as fast as possible.

And one unrelated thing - you can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` as a substitution of `android.text.TextUtils` - it has roughly the same functionality but you won't need to mock it in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for another thread to complete you can use this Mockito feature: [verify with timeout](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22).

```
verify(view, timeout(100)).updateView(any(PriceAndStockActivityViewModel.class));
```

Or use some means of thread synchronization like [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). See example for Mockito [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944544/697313).

Comment: it's not just something about threading problem. I believe that there must be an issue with rxjava...

Comment: @MustafaGüven Have you tried adding timeout? I don't see anything RxJava specific here.