# How to unit test a code snippet running inside executor service, instead waiting on Thread.sleep(time)

Tags: java, unit-testing, executorservice

How to unit test a code that is running in executor service?
In my situation,

```
public void test() {
    Runnable R = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            executeTask1();
            executeTask2();
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(R);
}
```

When I am unit testing, I would like to make some validations that method executes.

I am executing this in an executor service, as it makes some network operations.

In my unit testing, I had to wait until this method finishes execution. Is there a better way I can do this, instead of waiting for `Thread.sleep(500)`.

Unit testing code snippet:

```
@Test
public void testingTask() {
    mTestObject.test();
    final long threadSleepTime = 10000L;
    Thread.sleep(threadSleepTime);
    verify(abc, times(2))
            .acquireClient(a, b, c);
    verify(abd, times(1)).addCallback(callback);
}
```

Note: I am passing an executor service object into this constructor class.
I would like to know if there is a good way of testing instead of waiting for sleep time.

Answer (score 35):

You could also implement an ExecutorService yourself that will run the task in the same thread. For example:

```
public class CurrentThreadExecutor implements Executor {
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }
}
```

And then you could inherit from `AbstractExecutorService` and use this implementation.

If you're using Guava, another easy one is to use [MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#newDirectExecutorService%28%29) since that does the same thing without you having to create one yourself.

Comment: and would you suggest using this implementation to mock a `ScheduledExecutorService` as well?

Comment: In my case I explicitly want to test a snippet running in another thread, as that thread won't have the JPA EntityManager of the original thread. Just wanted to mention that this is not a solution for such a case.

Answer (score 13):

Google Guava provides a great class called `MoreExecutors` which helped me out when testing code that runs in parallel threads via `Executor` or `ExecutorService` in JUnit. It lets you create `Executor` instances that just run everything in the same thread, essentially as a mock of a real `Executor`. The issue is when things get run in other threads that JUnit isn't aware of, so these `Executors` from `MoreExecutors` make everything much easier to test since it's not *actually* parallel in another thread.

See the `MoreExecutors` documentation https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html

You can modify your class constructor, or add a new constructor that you only use in tests, which lets you provide your own `Executor` or `ExecutorService`. Then pass in the one from `MoreExecutors`.

So in the test file you'd create the mock executor using `MoreExecutors`

```
ExecutorService mockExecutor = MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService();

// or if you're using Executor instead of ExecutorService you can do MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutor()

MyService myService = new MyService(mockExecutor);
```

Then in your class, you only create a real Executor if it wasn't provided in the constructor

```
public MyService() {}
    ExecutorService threadPool;

    public MyService(ExecutorService threadPool) {
        this.threadPool = threadPool;
    }

    public void someMethodToTest() {
        if (this.threadPool == null) {
            // if you didn't provide the executor via constructor in the unit test, 
            // it will create a real one
            threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        }
        threadPool.execute(...etc etc)
        threadPool.shutdown()
    }
}
```

Comment: The shutdown call there will effectively cause that method to "block" until the Runnable completes though, you may want to call shutdown in your unit test instead...

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Future instance returned by executorService.submit(R).

From documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)

Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that task. **The Future's get method will return null upon successful completion.**

Example:

```
@Test
void test() throws ExecutionException {
    Future<Boolean> result = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
        int answer = 43;
        assertEquals(42, answer);
        return true;
    }
    assertTrue(result.get());
}
```

The inner assertion will throw an exception, which causes `result.get()` to throw its own exception. Thus the test will fail, and the exception's cause will tell you why ("Expected 42, but was 43 instead").

Comment: This is pretty much how I solved it, and is in my opinion the best answer among the ones proposed here.

Comment: Returning a Future and calling get on it works, or returning a straight Thread object and calling join on it (if you can get away without using an ExecutorService), or calling shutdown on the ExecutorService (same thing, does a join)

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- Extract the code out of the executor service and test it 'stand alone' i.e in your example test `executeTask1()` and `executeTask2()` on their own or even together but just not by executing them in a separate thread. The fact that you are "passing an executor service object into this constructor class" helps here since you could have

  - A test which mocks the executor service and verifies that you submit the correct runnable to it
  - Test(s) which verify the behaviour of `executeTask1()` and `executeTask2()` without running them in a separate thread.
- Use a `CountDownLatch` to allow your code-in-executor-service to indicate to the test thread when it is finished. For example:

  ```
  // this will be initialised and passed into the task which is run by the ExecutorService 
  // and will be decremented by that task on completion
  private CountDownLatch countdownLatch; 

  @Test(timeout = 1000) // just in case the latch is never decremented
  public void aTest() {
      // run your test

      // wait for completion
      countdownLatch.await();

      // assert 
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Accept that you have to wait for the other thread to complete and hide the ugliness of `Thread.sleep` calls in your test cases by using [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/). For example:

  ```
  @Test
  public void aTest() {
      // run your test

      // wait for completion
      await().atMost(1, SECONDS).until(taskHasCompleted());

      // assert 
      // ...
  }

  private Callable<Boolean> taskHasCompleted() {
      return new Callable<Boolean>() {
          public Boolean call() throws Exception {
              // return true if your condition has been met
              return ...;
          }
      };
  }
  ```

Comment: But note that my methods, say here executeTask1() and executeTask2(), here are private methods and they don't have any return types. I am not finding this way of testing reliable. Can you suggest why this is reliable way ?

Comment: I don't think I can offer much help on the specifics of testing `executeTask1()` and `executeTask2()` without seeing their implementation. I don't think I can offer any help with this: "I am not finding this way of testing reliable" without seeing what you have tried so far. If you are trying to rework your code to facilitate either option 1 or option 2 from my answer  then perhaps a separate question which addresses your specific issues and provides a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment of @ejfrancis, in my case what I did, is that since it was a local variable, I would move it to be a member variable and from there, I would simply use reflection in the test (probably reflection is not the best approach to go, but it will be less changes)

```
class MyClass {
            private final ExecutorService executorService = 
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);;
}
```

Then from here I would just go in my test after the creation of the class like this:

```
@BeforeEach
void init(){
   MyClass myClass = new Class();
   ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "executorService", MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService());
}
```

Comment: Did you know that ‘I’ is written as a capital letter? Apart from that, good to see `ReflectionTestUtils`, but inversion of control is still much better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control the Executor, you can issue a shutdown on it:

```
ExecutorService myExecutorService = ...;
mTestObject = new TestObject(myExecutorService);
mTestObject.test();
myExecutorService.shutdown(); // this will wait for submitted jobs to finish, like a join
// now do asserts
```

Or even if you have a getter for it, possibly same deal.

If you're real desperate you may be able to use a ThreadPoolExecutor instantiation of ExecutorService which has a `getActiveCount()` method and wait till it drops to zero...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `executor.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS)` as this will block and execute tasks waiting for execution after that you can see result and continue test code like in this one:

```
@Test
fun testFileJsonStore() {
    val store = CSFileJsonStore(context, "file")
    val property: StoreTypesTestData by store.property("property")
    assertEquals(5, property.int)

    property.string = "new value"
    property.int = 123
    property.jsonObject.lateString = "new value"
    executor.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS)
    assertEquals(
        """{"property":{"key1":"new value","key2":123,"key3":{"lateStringId":"new value"}}}""",
        store.file.readString())

    val store2: CSStore = CSFileJsonStore(context, "file")
    val property2: StoreTypesTestData by store2.property("property")
    assertEquals("new value", property2.string)
    assertEquals(123, property2.int)
    assertEquals("new value", property2.jsonObject.lateString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control what `abd` is and can make it a mock, you could set a timeout that it be called eventually: [Mockito: wait for an invocation that matches arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944202/mockito-wait-for-an-invocation-that-matches-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin with mockk, mocked ScheduledExecutorService is the way to go.

```
class MyExecutorClass() {
    fun executeSomething() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule( {
                // do something here
            }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}
       
@Test
fun myExecutorTest() {
    // setup
    val capturingSlotRunnable: CapturingSlot<Runnable> = slot()
    mockkStatic(Executors::class)
    val mockExecutor: ScheduledExecutorService = mockk(relaxed = true)
    every { Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() } returns mockExecutor
    every { mockExecutor.schedule(capture(capturingSlotRunnable), any(), any()) } returns null
    
    // execute
    val myExecutor = MyExecutorClass()
    myExecutor.executeSomething()
    val runnable = capturingSlotRunnable.captured
    runnable.run()

    // verify
    // TODO: verify the executable block did whatever it was supposed to
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework provides `SyncTaskExecutor` which implements `TaskExecutor` hence `Executor`.
It simply executes the `Runnable` right away

```
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        Assert.notNull(task, "Runnable must not be null");
        task.run();
    }
```

In order to make all Spring `@Service`s make use of this `Executor` you can provide a `@TestConfiguration` class somewhere in the *src/test/java* folder.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
  
  @Bean
  public Executor syncTaskExecutor() {
    return new SyncTaskExecutor();
  }
}
```

[@TestConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html) is very useful for overriding some `@Bean`s only for the scope of test execution. According to its documentation:

> @Configuration that can be used to define additional beans or
> customizations for a test. Unlike regular @Configuration classes the
> use of @TestConfiguration does not prevent auto-detection of
> @SpringBootConfiguration.

After that the test class should be annotated with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mock
ExecutorService executorService;


@Test
public void testExecutorService() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Set the Mock ExecuotService to your testing class or service
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "executorService", executorService);
    
    // Mock data 
    SomeEntity entity = buildSomeEntity();
    
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        // This is to mock your actual task execution
        when(respository.save(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(entity);
        
        Runnable runnable = invocation.getArgument(0);
        runnable.run();
        return null;
    }).when(executorService).submit(any(Runnable.class));

    service.createEntity(Params....);
```